# In React app <a> tag link isn't redirecting to another website

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React. I'm building a map with markers that will have a popup window which contains a link that once clicked will redirect to another website. I am using see more however when I click on it nothing happens. I do however see the redirection website link on the bottom. I'm using [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) as an example. I am trying all this in localhost. Here's a snippet from my code.

```js
function App() {

    const [viewport, setViewport] = useState({
      latitude: 40.68313619450496,
      longitude:-73.98128935812457,
      width: "100vw",
      height: "100vh",
      zoom: 10
    });

    const[selectedField, setSelectedField] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
      const listener = e => {
        if (e.key === "Escape") {
          setSelectedField(null);
        }
      };
      window.addEventListener("keydown", listener);
    }, []);
    return (
     <div>
      <ReactMapGl
        {...viewport}
        mapboxApiAccessToken="***"
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/valram/ckf2tl39x01hi19jwu9e8alzp"
        onViewportChange={viewport => {
          setViewport(viewport);
       }}
       >
        {fieldData.map((field) => (
          <Marker
            key={field.field_id}
            latitude={field.coordinates[0]}
            longitude={field.coordinates[1]}
          >
           <button
             className="marker-btn"
             onClick={(e) => {
              e.preventDefault();
              setSelectedField(field);
            }}
           >
             <img src= "/ball.png" alt="field icon" />
           </button>
          </Marker>
        ))}

        {selectedField ? (
          <Popup
            latitude={selectedField.coordinates[0]}
            longitude={selectedField.coordinates[1]}
            onClose={() => {
              setSelectedField(null);
            }}
          >
            <div>
              <h2>{selectedField.name}</h2>
              <p>{selectedField.address}</p>
              <img width={240} src={selectedField.image} />
              <a href="https://www.google.com/"> see more </a>

            </div>
          </Popup>
          ) : null}
        }
      </ReactMapGl>
     </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Do you want to redirect to another page in the same site or to external site?

Comment: We cant help you that way. <a> works that way. I think the variable you give to the href-attribute is probably undefined, or the link is broken. We would need a specific example where you are geeting this link from. Is selectedField.link defined?? You would need to do <a href={selectedField.link} > Click me </a>

Comment: replace the anchor with a div and place a click handler

Comment: It is for the external site. For now, I am using google homepage as the external site. I set up a dummy json file which has a link property. Using <a href={selectedField.link}> see more </a> didn't work. I will post my full app.js code.

Comment: There is a type on a href, you forgot a quote <a href="https://www.google.com/> see more </a> -> <a href="https://www.google.com/"> see more </a>

Comment: Thank you! Fixed the typo but that wasn't it.